Why does it seem from Rabbeinu Shimshon that מי חטאת are Machshir?
The Mishnah (Parah 11:7) says that one should not use hyssop of Terumah for the purpose of spraying מי חטאת, and Rabbi Shimshon of Shantz explains that one of the reasons is in order that it should not become מוכשר לקבל טומאה.
My question is: why would מי חטאת be Machshir - isn’t there a rule (see commentaries on the Mishnah, Machshirin 6:4) that anything that has a שם לווי (additional name) is not Machshir? (see Zevachim 22b that ״מי כיור״ are considered to have a שם לווי, so ״מי חטאת״ should seemingly be the same).

It could be not because water went on it (which is machshir for plants) but because this gives it purpose as a k'li (which don't need to touch liquids in order to be muchshar). Not sure if that's true though

@Loani - that would be a nice explanation, but it seems from the next Mishnah that even if you gathered the hyssop with the intention to use it for purification, that it would need to come in contact with liquid in order for it to become Muchshar, (and some say that even then it does not become Muchshar) so it seems that designating it for purification does not give it the purpose of a K’li.

There has to be a limit to what's included in שם לווי.  There are things like מי באר or מי גשמים or tap water.

@Heshy - it seems that the שם לווי of water designated for a Mitzvah, such as ״מי כיור״ has a special חשיבות.

The mishna speaks about hyssop of terumah which is already susceptible to tumah, i.e. it can be impure or pure. It teaches that hyssop of terumah that is impure, even if it is less that an egg size and would not make impure the מי חטאת, is still forbidden for sprinling since it is impure. The same is true for hyssop of chulin which is impure. In the case of the hyssop of terumah that is pure there are two cases:

If the size of hyssop less than an egg, the hyssop that was prepared with purity stringencies of teruma would still be considered impure relative the stringences required for מי חטאת.
Even if the size is more than an egg and the terumah was prepared with stringencies fitting for מי חטאת, one would still not use it for sprinkling, for perhaps accidentally there will be psul for sprinkling which will cause the מי חטאת cause impurity to the terumah and cause it to be disqualified.

The relevant part to the OP's question is the second part of the Rabbeinu Shimshon to Parah 11:7 comment:

ושל תרומה. שלקטו לאכילה דחייב בתרומה ודאי דפסול בתרומה טמאה כדתנן לקמן בפ"ב (מ"ו) דאזוב טמא הזאתו פסולה והוא הדין של חולין טמאין ואגב סיפא דמחלק בתרומה טהורה דלכתחלה לא יזה נקט רישא תרומה וטעמא דלא יזה בטהורה כדאמרינן בסוכה (דף לה:) גבי אתרוג פליגי בה ר' אמי ור' אסי חד אמר מפני שמכשירה וחד אמר מפני שמפסידה:
The hyssop was picked for eating is liable for terumah. Obviously, (sprinkiling) is disqualified for impure terumah, because it is taught in Mishnah 15:9 (the numbering is different), the hyssop that is impure is disqualified from sprinkling. The same is true with hyssop of impure chulin. The second part regarding hyssop of pure terumah, there is a distinction, lehatchila one should not sprinkle, as it is said in Succah 35b regarding esrog of terumah. There R' Ami and R' Asi argue about esrog of terumah taken for the mitzvah of lulav and becoming wet, whether it would make it susceptible to tumah or whether it will spoil it.

One must conclude that the esrog in Gemara Succah was only designated for terumah, but remained tevel. This is different from the case of the mishnah, where the hyssop of terumah is already susceptible to tumah. Alternatively, if our hyssop is only designated for terumah (with all stringencies of מי חטאת), but not rendered susceptible, we should not use it lehatchila because מי חטאת will makhshir it and there may occur an accident which will disqualify it by impurity.
